# install skdata in python3

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm having some trouble installing skdata with Python3. What am I doing wrong? My current python version is 3.5.2. Here's my console output.

```
$ pip install skdata
Collecting skdata
  Using cached skdata-0.0.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    RefactoringTool: Can't open /private/var/folders/b_/v88qj4rx52z9mmx67tlwkcpm0000gn/T/pip-build-_q95pm4w/skdata/build/py3k: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/b_/v88qj4rx52z9mmx67tlwkcpm0000gn/T/pip-build-_q95pm4w/skdata/build/py3k'
    RefactoringTool: No files need to be modified.
    RefactoringTool: There was 1 error:
    RefactoringTool: Can't open /private/var/folders/b_/v88qj4rx52z9mmx67tlwkcpm0000gn/T/pip-build-_q95pm4w/skdata/build/py3k: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/b_/v88qj4rx52z9mmx67tlwkcpm0000gn/T/pip-build-_q95pm4w/skdata/build/py3k'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/b_/v88qj4rx52z9mmx67tlwkcpm0000gn/T/pip-build-_q95pm4w/skdata/setup.py", line 64, in <module>
        raise Exception('2to3 failed, exiting ...')
    Exception: 2to3 failed, exiting ...
    Copying source tree into build/py3k for 2to3 transformation...
    Converting to Python3 via 2to3...

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/b_/v88qj4rx52z9mmx67tlwkcpm0000gn/T/pip-build-_q95pm4w/skdata/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check-out the repo and copy the /skdata/skdata directory in the  /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ directory

See this github thread for more information:

https://github.com/jaberg/skdata/issues/63